# Configure google material components web in laravel project

Tags: laravel, npm, material-components-web

Can someone explain to me how I can install Google Material Components Web in a Laravel 10 project?
I tried to follow the online documentation, but I can't get it to work.
This is the link I followed to install Material Web Components: [text](https://github.com/material-components/material-web/blob/main/docs/quick-start.md)

Thank you very much for your help!